# Place ht access file in webroot of each directory bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, apache-httpd, cp

I'm trying to write a script that will descend into each subdirectory in /home and find the public_html folder within.

Then it will check if an .htaccess already exists, if it does write that to a file, if it doesn't exist place the .htaccess file in public_html

Right now I have

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=.htaccess
for d in */; do
cd "${D}"
cd public_hmtl
if [-e $FILE ]; then
echo "Htaccess exists for "${D}" >> /test/error.txt
else
cp /htaccess ./
fi
```

This is obviously not right as it doesn't even run. I haven't had much experience with bash and it's been awhile since I've needed to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

htaccess='/path/to/.htaccess'

for dir in /home/*/public_html/; do
    if [ -e "$dir/.htaccess" ]; then
        print 'htaccess exists in "%s"\n' >&2
    else
        cp "$htaccess" "$dir"
    fi
done
```

This iterates over all `public_html` directories in each directory under `/home` and checks to see if there's already a `.htaccess` file in there.  If there is, a diagnostic message is produced, otherwise a standard `.htaccess` is copied from somewhere.

You would run this with

```
$ ./script 2>error.log
```

---

The issue with your code is the `cd`.  It changes directory down to one of the `public_html` directories (if run from within `/home`), but never comes back up again.